# How do I update each element in a list using Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if there was a possible way to update data of each elements in the list

This is my initial list,

```
var list1 = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png']
```

I want the final list in such a way that I could update the all the elements in the list like, (just add a string at the beginning of the elements)

```
var list1 = ['bucket/image1.png', 'bucket/image2.png', 'bucket/image3.png]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can like this:

```dart
List result = list1.map((e) => 'bucket/$e').toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *mutate* the original `List` instead of creating a new `List`, just use a loop:

```dart
var list1 = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'];
for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i += 1) {
  list1[i] = 'bucket/${list1[i]}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this either

```
var list1 = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'];
list1 = list1.map((item) => 'bucket/$item').toList();
```